# Python Matplotlib: Plotting data on Basemap at specific points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting weather model precipitation data on a map. The map is a contour fill. Over that data I would like to plot text at specific grid points that tells the value of the precipitation at the point in time, however I am struggling to do this. I have a list of lat/lon points but cannot figure out how to map it properly to the data I have. The data itself comes with it's own set of lat/lon points that uniquely map to the data. Here's example code that I have:

```
grib = 'gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p25.f084'
grbs = pygrib.open(grib)

grb = grbs.select(name='Total Precipitation',typeOfLevel='surface')[0]
precip = grb.values *.039370
lat,lon = grb.latlons()
x, y = m(lon,lat)

with open('mydata') as f:
    for line in f:
        myline = line.replace("\n", "")
        myline = myline.split(",")
        uniquepoints.append(myline) # contains specific lat, lon points

intervals = [0.0,0.01,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.00,1.25,1.50,1.75,2.0,2.50,3.00]

m=Basemap(projection='lcc',lon_0 = -95.,llcrnrlon=-125.,
  urcrnrlon=-55.,llcrnrlat=20.,urcrnrlat=50., lat_1=25.,lat_2=46., resolution='l',area_thresh=10000,ax=ax)

obsobj = m.contourf(x,y,precip,intervals,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

I know you are suppose to use plt.text, but I can't configure it correctly so that the unique points map correctly to the precip data.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easy to make simple mistakes with placing points on Basemap as you have to convert between lat,long,height and the windows coordinate system in x,y. However, if your data is plotting at the correct points on the map, you can use those positions to plot your labels at those exact points with some specified offset.

A pythonic example of how to do this:

```
lats = [x['LLHPosition'][0] for x in unit_data]
lons = [x['LLHPosition'][1] for x in unit_data]
x,y = m(lons,lats)

label_text = [x['UnitName'] for x in unit_data]
x_offsets = [2000] * len(unit_data)
y_offsets = [2000] * len(unit_data)

for label, xpt, ypt, x_offset, y_offset in zip(label_text, x, y, x_offsets, y_offsets):
    plt.text(xpt+x_offset, ypt+y_offset, label)
```